# Solving Arc tan using Taylor series

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, taylor-series

I want to solve arctan (x) using a Taylor series but my code doesn't work. How do I solve this?

```
#!usr/bin/python


from numpy import *    

def err(string):
    print string
    raw_input ('Press Enter to Exit')
    sys.exit()

def postive_term(x)
    sum_i = 0.0
    for i in range(50):
        Y(i) = 1**((4.0*i)+1.0)/((4.0*i)+1.0)
    sum_i = Y(i)
    return sum_i

def negatif_term(x)
    sum_j = 0.0
    for j in range(50):
        S(j) = 1**((4.0*j)+3.0)/((4.0*j)+3.0)
    sum_j = S(j)
    return sum_j                   

u(i) = sum_i - sum_j

print 'result Tan^{-1} (x)=', u(i)`
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "my code doesn't work".

Comment: The line `u(i) = sum_i = sum_j` is syntactically invalid python. Diddo with `S(j)=[math]` and `Y(i) = [math]`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few syntax errors in the code including the way you get the user input and how you call the two functions for the positive and negative terms; a working version is below.  Note that this only converges in the interval (-1,1), which you can check with the `atan` function from the `math` package.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def positive_term(x):
    sum_i = float(x)
    for i in range(1,50):
        sum_i += x**((4*i) + 1) / (4.0*i + 1.0)
    return sum_i

def negative_term(x):
    sum_i = 0.0
    for i in range(1,50):
        sum_i += x**((4*i)-1)/(4.0*i - 1.0)
    return sum_i

x = float(sys.argv[1])
print 'result Tan^{-1} (%.1f)= %.5f' % (x, positive_term(x) - negative_term(x))
```

Comment: You'll need to provide an argument (value of x) when you execute it, i.e. '>> python mycode.py 1.0'